# Adding .txt file that in csv format as a sheet to existing workbook in C#

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a .txt file that is already in Comma-separated values (csv) format.
I want to add the data in the .txt file as a sheet to an open Excel workbook.

this is how I open the workbook:

```
var xlApp = new Excel.Application { Visible = false };
Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
```

And this is how I try to add the .txt file to the workbook:

```
string txt2xls = Globals.HomeDir + "\\JSL\\Data1" + ".txt";
string csv2xls = Globals.HomeDir + "\\JSL\\Data1" + ".csv";

if (File.Exists(csv2xls))
File.Delete(csv2xls);

File.Move(txt2xls, Path.ChangeExtension(txt2xls, ".csv"));
newWorkbook.Sheets.Add(csv2xls, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

The last line gave me an error (HRESULT: 0x800A03EC).
What can i do to solved this problem?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV file in Excel can have **allways only one worksheet**. You cannot add another sheet as CSV. You will have to open the CSV separately as another Workbook and copy the Worksheet from that Workbook to your multi-sheet xlsx Workbook `newWorkbook`.

Use `Worksheet.Copy` method as described in [How to: Programmatically Copy Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178800.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.copy%28VS.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

```
var xlApp = new Excel.Application { Visible = false };
Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Excel.Workbook csvWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(csv2xls);
Excel.Worksheet worksheetCSV = ((Excel.Worksheet)csvWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
Excel.Worksheet targetWorksheet = ((Excel.Worksheet)newWorkbook.Worksheets[1]);
worksheetCSV.Copy(targetWorksheet);
```

Also mark that

> If you do not specify either Before or After, Microsoft Office Excel
>   creates a new workbook that contains the copied sheet.

So you can do

```
worksheetCSV.Copy(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

and no need to explitly Add `newWorkbook`.

Comment: Thank you!
Do you know how to copy the workbook as you describes using C#?